# UWP Window content doe not resize with window

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

I started to develop my first UWP App (just for fun). While debugging I noticed that the content would not adapt correctly when resizing the window. I started over with an empty app to see, if it was a general problem: it is.

**TL;DR:**
Why does this happen when resizing the window larger (beyond 1246x936 px)? Notice the issue on the very right.

[image: Notice the issue on the very right]

That's the XAML code:

```
<Page
    x:Class="App2.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:App2"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="White">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Column="0" Background="Blue" />
        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Background="Red" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: That seems like a rendering bug (even the TitleBar is _outside_ the window). Have you tried restarting your PC? Had the same problem few times but after restart it was gone.

Comment: @MarianDolinský Just wow… after trying to fix this for 2 hours. I think this is what you get, when Windows does an update without notifying you.

Comment: Yeah, they were doing some changes in UWP rendering in Creators Update. Before I've never met with this issue.

Comment: Use it as reference https://github.com/JustinXinLiu/AdaptiveLayoutAnimation?files=1

Answer (score 1):

Little late but for posterity as this issue still comes up:

This behavior is most likely related to UWP and your video drivers.  I have had this issue and it also extended into official Microsoft Windows Store UWP apps (Weather, Calc, etc) verifying it was not something I caused.

If you're lucky and have video driver updates, install them and it will likely fix the issue (it did for me on two different computers, one with an AMD card the other with Intel graphics).  If your video drivers are out of support there may not be a path forward (although the app would work on workstations whose drivers did render it correctly).

There are a few tips on this thread that -may- work for workarounds for yourself (but aren't ideal if you're distributing your program and actually need it to render consistently).

https://superuser.com/questions/1376099/windows-10-uwp-not-rendering-fully

- Run Performance Options (SystemPropertiesPerformance.exe) and uncheck "Show window contents while dragging".  Then reboot.
- Resize the window, then close and reopen the application, and it might then be of the right size.

Comment: I've a laptop w/ Intel & a desktop w/ nVidia & it's been happening on both >2 years (ever since a certain windows update). Will try driver updates again but I'm not holding my breath. Seems to happen after it's been running a while (in Settings, Sticky Notes, Calculator...) and only a reboot ever fixes it. (Temporary workaround: resize the app larger to the desired size, close and reopen.)